# PyCharm Remote Debugging with Windows

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to remotely debug. My remote host is ubuntu server and my client (local?) is my laptop with Windows 10. Below is the error message I am encountering.

I am having a trouble with configuring debugger. I was using linux before - I could set port number for each debugger configuration by typing in numbers. But with Windows PyCharm, I have no option to choose port number. Anyways, when I start a debugger, port number is displayed on the debugger console window : 45344. So I typed in the port number 45344 for my python script which I executed at the remote host. But remote-debugging failed as below. Could anyone help me?

```
Could not connect to 192.168.1.254: 45344
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycharm-debug.egg/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 489, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Very late comment, but in case someone reached this question: [Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226455) are some updates about remote development support. For your specific issue, I see a space in front of your port number in the error description. Maybe it is that easy?!